# if statement with javascript condition operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

just have 2 question regarding JS conditional operator, is the below 2 expression valid?

1.

```
if(isUser && isUser === true || isGuest && isGuest === true){
     //...
   }
```

I am wondering do I have to add () to make it like and still have the same functioning:

```
if((isUser && isUser === true) || (isGuest && isGuest === true)){
     //...
   }
```

2. 

```
const items = list.orderList && list.orderList.isUser === true || list.orderList.isGuest ? list.items : [];
```

I am wondering do I have to add () to make it like and functioning the same as above conditional operator:

```
const items = list.orderList && (list.orderList.isUser === true || list.orderList.isGuest === true) ? list.items : [];
```

Comment: Think of `&&` and `||` as `*` and `+`. The `&&` operator binds more tightly than `||`.

Comment: Yes, the expressions in #1 are equivalent, but really you should write just `if (isUser || isGuest)` (or `if (isUser === true || isGuest === true)` if the variables can hold non-boolean values, but you should avoid that). The expressions in #2 are not equivalent.

Comment: Compare `false && false || true` vs `false && (false || true)` in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) in the MDN docs, logical AND takes precedence over logical OR. Therefore,

```
expression1 || expression2 && expression3
```

will evaluate to

```
expression1 || (expression2 && expression3)
```

Therefore,

```
isUser && isUser === true || isGuest && isGuest === true
```

naturally evaluates to

```
(isUser && isUser === true) || (isGuest && isGuest === true)
```

anyway, so you do not need parentheses..

But since, in your second example, you want to evaluate OR *then* AND, you *do* need parentheses for it to evaluate the way you require, as

```
list.orderList && list.orderList.isUser === true || list.orderList.isGuest
```

will evaluate to

```
(list.orderList && list.orderList.isUser === true) || list.orderList.isGuest
```

Comment: `statement1 && statement2 || statement3` is pretty unambiguous since it would be evaluated the same if operator precedence would be the same and evaluation just left-to-right. `statement1 || statement2 && statement3` = `statement1 || (statement2 && statement3)` might be a better example.

Comment: (Also, it should be `expressionX` not `statementX`)